# How to bind to Button's foreground color?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have Path element inside my button, and I want it to change color when the button is pressed. Binding to Foreground property doesn't seem to work. The simplified code is below, especially important is this bit: Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=SwitchLanguages}" on Path element. I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but for some reason I was not able to find it.

```
   <Button 
        Name="SwitchLanguages" 
        Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <Canvas
            Width="46.5" 
            Height="44" 
            Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
            <Path 
                Width="46.4999" 
                Height="44" 
                Canvas.Left="0" 
                Canvas.Top="0" 
                Stretch="Fill" 
                Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=SwitchLanguages}"
                Data="F1 M 22,52.0001L 22,44.0001L 46.75,44.0001L 38.75,36L 49.25,36L 61.25,48.0001L 49.25,60L 38.75,60L 46.75,52.0001L 22,52.0001 Z M 54,23.9999L 54,31.9999L 29.25,31.9999L 37.25,40L 26.75,40L 14.75,27.9999L 26.75,16L 37.25,16L 29.25,23.9999L 54,23.9999 Z ">
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Does the color of `SwitchLanguages` change on click? It won't if you haven't done something special.

Comment: The color does actually change when pressed (not the `Foreground` property of the control, but its content's color) -- this is based on the Button's default template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check "System.Windows.xaml" in the SDK, you will see that it's actually a template child that has its Foreground modified when the button is pressed, not the control's `Foreground` property itself.

The ideal approach here will be to modify the `Template` of the Button control.  That way you can put the `Path` there, and modify its color as needed using the "Pressed" `VisualState` storyboard.  For example, the below modifies the default `ControlTemplate`, adding your `Path` element and modifying its `Fill` property when the "Pressed" visual state is triggered:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Grid Background="Transparent">

          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

          <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" >

            <Canvas
                Width="46.5" 
                Height="44" 
                Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
                <Path x:Name="ContentContainer"
                    Width="46.4999" 
                    Height="44" 
                    Canvas.Left="0" 
                    Canvas.Top="0" 
                    Stretch="Fill" 
                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Data="F1 M 22,52.0001L 22,44.0001L 46.75,44.0001L 38.75,36L 49.25,36L 61.25,48.0001L 49.25,60L 38.75,60L 46.75,52.0001L 22,52.0001 Z M 54,23.9999L 54,31.9999L 29.25,31.9999L 37.25,40L 26.75,40L 14.75,27.9999L 26.75,16L 37.25,16L 29.25,23.9999L 54,23.9999 Z ">
                </Path>
            </Canvas>

          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Put the above in your application resources, and use it like this:

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick event change the button's foreground color such as

```
SwitchLanguages.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
```

That will change the binding's color for your path item due to its binding.

Comment: This is not the best solution -- you would need to add another event handler to switch the color back.  Better to hook into the "Pressed" VisualState in the ControlTemplate.

Comment: @McGarnagle My intent was to simply provide a simple solution to a person who is learning about Xaml development. Nothing more nothing less. If the ends justifies the means, I leave that up to the end user.

Comment: @OmegaMan I know I could try to change the color in code-behind, but I am sure that there has to be a better way do to this.